# How to access a variable declared in a phtml from another phtml?

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml, phtml, product-view

I have inserted two blocks in the `catalog_product_view.xml` file:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.custom-product-attributes" template="product/view/custom-product-attributes.phtml" after="product.info.overview"/>
...
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.custom-estimated-delivery" template="product/view/custom-estimated-delivery.phtml" after="product.price.final"/>
```

How can I access a variable declared in the first block from the second block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the variable with `register` from the first phtml, then you get the value in the 2nd phtml with `registry`

To do things well without injecting direclty the objectManager in phtml, you have to create some function your product block, so:

In your block : `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Custom.php`

assuming that your variable name is : `$tech`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Block;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Set var data
     */
    public function setTechData($data)
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('tech', $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get var data
     */
    public function getTechData()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('tech');
    }
}
```

So in your First phtml :

```
<?php $tech = 'Your Data here'; ?>
<?php $block->setTechData($tech); ?>
```

In the Second phtml :

```
<?php $block->getTechData(); ?> //you'll get your tech value here
```

You can do that in phtml to **test** without the block solution :

First phtml :

```
<?php 
$tech = 'Your Data here';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->create("Magento\Framework\Registry")->register('tech', $tech);
?>
```

Second phtml :

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$techData = $objectManager->create("Magento\Framework\Registry")->registry('tech');
echo $techData;
?>
```